# Remove duplicates in multiple columns and rows based on rule

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements

Suppose I have the following data:

```
dt <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,7),
             rk=c("a","a","b","b","c","y","c","d","e","y","e","e","f","g","h"),
             .id=c("df1", "df9", "df5", "df16", "df2", "df11", "df11", "df4", "df9", "df4", "df6", "df3", "df16", "df2", "df9"))
```

So my data looks like this:

```
id   rk  .id
1    a   df1
1    a   df9
2    b   df5
2    b  df16
3    c   df2
3    y  df11
3    c  df11
4    d   df4
5    e   df9
5    y   df4
5    e   df6
5    e   df3
6    f  df16
7    g   df2
7    h   df9
```

But I only want *one* row per pair of **id** and **rk**. 
So in the example id=5 can have two rows: one with rk=e and one with rk=y.

To find the right row to keep I look to the **.id** column. Here I prioritize in the following order:

**df2, df9, df1, df5, df4, df6, df15, df17, df16, df14, df8, df11, df3, df7, df12, df13, df10**

So I would always keep a row with .id=df2 over a row with .id=df9. Likewise I would always keep a row with .id=df15 over a row with .id=df14.

Note, that the order is not chronological.

Back to my example data, this is what I would like to end up with:

```
id   rk  .id
1    a   df9
2    b   df5
3    c   df2
3    y  df11
4    d   df4
5    e   df9
5    y   df4
6    f  df16
7    g   df2
7    h   df9
```

My dataset is huge, so I hope some of you can help me writing some code that makes this easy peasy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `dplyr` we can `group_by` `id` and `rk` and get the first `match` of `.id` with `new_order`.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  group_by(id, rk) %>%
  summarise(.id = .id[which.min(match(.id, new_order))])

#   id rk    .id  
#   <dbl> <fct> <fct>
# 1  1.00 a     df9  
# 2  2.00 b     df5  
# 3  3.00 c     df2  
# 4  3.00 y     df11 
# 5  4.00 d     df4  
# 6  5.00 e     df9  
# 7  5.00 y     df4  
# 8  6.00 f     df16 
# 9  7.00 g     df2  
#10  7.00 h     df9
```

---

Equivalent, base R `aggregate` option is

```
aggregate(.id~id+rk, dt, function(x) x[which.min(match(x, new_order))])
```

---

If there are some other columns which we want to keep, we can use `filter` instead of `summarise`

```
dt %>%
 group_by(id, rk) %>%
 filter(.id == .id[which.min(match(.id, new_order))])
```

---

whose equivalent `ave` option would be

```
dt[with(dt, .id ==  ave(.id, id, rk, FUN = function(x) 
                    x[which.min(match(x, new_order))])), ]
```

where ,

```
new_order <- c("df2", "df9", "df1", "df5", "df4", "df6", "df15", "df17", "df16",
           "df14", "df6", "df8", "df11", "df3", "df7", "df12", "df13", "df10")
```

Comment: Okay I have a follow up question.,. I have one more column in the data. I didn't put it in the example data, but that's really the column I'm interested in finding the right one of. How do I keep this column after the grouping? I've tried putting it in the group_by, but then (obviously) it groups by this column too - and I don't want that.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `data.table` like this. Looks slightly long but fairly intuitive.

```
library(data.table)

# Load datasets
dt <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,7,7),
                 rk=c("a","a","b","b","c","y","c","d","e","y","e","e","f","g","h"),
                 .id=c("df1", "df9", "df5", "df16", "df2", "df11", "df11", "df4", "df9", "df4", "df6", "df3", "df16", "df2", "df9"))


Priority_List <- c("df2", "df9", "df1", "df5", "df4", "df6", "df15", "df17", "df16",
                   "df14", "df6", "df8", "df11", "df3", "df7", "df12", "df13", "df10")

# Create a data table called priority list with the priority rank
Priority_List <- data.table(.id = Priority_List , Priority = 1:length(Priority_List))

# Convert your parent data.frame into data.table
dt <- data.table(dt)

# Merge the Priority List with dt based on .id
dt <- merge(dt,Priority_List, by =c(".id"), all.x = TRUE)

# Find the minimum priority for each id and rk
dt <- dt[, Min_Priority := min(Priority), by = c("id", "rk")]

# Filter when Priority is equal to the Min_Priority for a particular id, rk
dt <- dt[Min_Priority == Priority]

# Take unique in case there are duplicate rows.
dt <- unique(dt)

# Remove unwanted columns and order based on id and rk
dt <- dt[,.(id, rk, .id)][order(id, rk)]
```

Hope this helps.